# Правопис слова «пиз(д)ливий»

Tags: правопис, прикметники, ненормативна-лексика, приголосні

Не сприйміть за жарт чи глузування. Хочеться щиро спитати про правопис одного нецензурного слова: пиз(д)ливий.

Це слово — лайливий, негативно забарвлений синонім до слова брехливий. Через відсутність словникового переліку матюків в українській мові правопис цього слова не відомий, попри те, що люди це слово вживають. Я намагався знайти, але не знайшов жодних інших слів із кореневим закінченням -зд і суфіксом -лив-. Але, як відомо, за правилами української мови, -зд+н- спрощується до -зн- (виїзний, а не виїздний), або -ст+л- до -сл- (щасливий, а не щастливий). Водночас, слово пестливий, яке дуже схоже на пиз(д)ливий — якраз виняток. От як дізнатися, відбувається тут спрощення чи ні?

Мені насправді здається, що тут, як і в слові пестливий, має бути виняток — тобто пиздливий, без спрощення.

Буду дуже вдячний за вашу аргументовану відповідь!

Comment: Слово має два суфікси: -л-, -ив-.

Comment: У буквосполученні -ЗДЛ- спрощення не відбувається. §28 https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf

Comment: @RomanMikhol А як щодо слова пиз(д)нути (у значенні вдарити)? За наведеним параграфом -здн- завжди скорочується, винятків не наведено. Тому тут зі скороченням?

Answer (score 2):

*Словник нецензурної лексики* Лесі Ставицької з вами погоджується і навіть наводить чудове ілюстративне речення:

> **ПИЗДЛИ́ВИЙ**, -а, -е, *обсц., згруб.-просто-розм.*, *презирл*. Який говорить нісенітницю. *І от знову тікаю в гори, до пиздливих богів питатися поради, шукати шляху* (І. Окуневський, Знадвору).

Загалом, схоже, слова із цим коренем не спрощуються — попереднє гасло там само:

> **ПИ́ЗДКА**, *ж.*, *фольк., обсц*. Те саме, що **ПИЗДА́**. *А знала, їбать твою мать, Хлопцям пиздки давать!* (Українські сороміцькі пісні).
> [Цитата з *Українські сороміцькі пісні* / Упорядкування, передмова, примітки М. М. Красикова. — Харків: Фоліо, 2003.]

Було б цікаво знайти більше прикладів і з'ясувати, чи часом відмінність від **проїзду** не в тому, що після -зд- у корені маємо голосну.
Upd: приклади з [правопису](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#spro) цю гіпотезу спростовують, бо **улесливий**, але **пестливий**.

Comment: В "проїзді" корінь "їзд", немає в корені голосної після д-. В чому саме полягає ваше запитання?

Comment: @RomanMikhol правда ваша, це дурниця, бо обидва корені закінчуються на приголосну. Умовно, питання про те, чи можна сформулювати просте правило про спрощення на підставі морфемного чи фонетичного складу. Але досить було перейти за посиланням на правопис у моїй відповіді, щоб зрозуміти, що це не так.